# Creating array of z-values from line vertices in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3, expression

I would like to create an array of a line's z-values to use as part of another expression. The z-values should be in the same order as the vertices, I would like to be able to use it as an input for `min()`, `max()` functions etc.

I have looked through the geometry and array expressions in the field calculator but I haven't found anything that works. I had an idea to count the number of points (`nump_points($geometry)`), and loop through the geometry pulling out z values at individual vertices but there's no loop function in the field calculator.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add a new function to get array of z-values from line vertices.

1. Open *Function Editor* tab in *Field Calculator* (or *Expression*) window. Create a new function by clicking plus icon. Enter a file name, e.g. `z_array_from_line`.
2. Copy/Paste the script. Then, click `Save and Load Functions` (or related button) to register the function. It's added 'Custom' group.

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *

   @qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
   def get_z_array_from_line_vertices(value1, feature, parent):
       z_array = [p.z() for p in feature.geometry().vertices()]
       return z_array
   ```
3. Now, you can use `get_z_array_from_line_vertices()` function in expressions.

The function gives you z-values in the same order as the vertices.

EDIT:
But `max()` function in Expression is expecting set of values like `max(1,2,3)`, not list or array like `max([1,2,3])`. If you need maximum value you can add python `max()` which excepts list to the definition of the function or save as a new one.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def max_z_value_from_line_vertices(value, feature, parent):
    z_array = [p.x() for p in feature.geometry().vertices()]
    return max(z_array)
```

Comment: Thanks. However when I try to use max() on the array it doesn't return anything, I think it's because max() is expecting a list or a set but not an array. How do I convert the array to a list?

Comment: You're right. But `max()` is expecting set of values like `max(1,2,3)`, not list or array like max([1,2,3]). If you need maximum value you can add `max` to the new function. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you want a loop function, the closest option is usually one of the Aggregate functions.

Use the `array_agg` function, which "Returns an array of aggregated values from a field or expression." To get an array of Z values, use:

```
 array_agg( z( $geometry))
```